# I am using Jersey and I am getting this error "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception"

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, jersey

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPMrR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPMrR.png)

this is my code. I am using Eclipse and I am using Apache tomcat 8.0. I am using Jersey to get this error "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init () for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception" I could not resolve the error. Do you have an idea?

**web.xml**

```
  servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.yakupcaglan</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
      <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
      <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**index.htlm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hi !!
</body>
</html>
```

**java class**

```
package com.yakupcaglan;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
public class mm {

@Path(value="/kullanici")   
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("hi !");
}
 // http://localhost:8080/deniyorummm/rest/kullanici/karsila
     @GET
     @Path(value="karsila")
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
     public String metot1() {
         return "hi RESTful";
     }
}
```

Tomcat...

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-servlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
    com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:226)
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:142)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.47 logs.
```

Comment: Can u try jersey-server 2.x version and test ?

Comment: The Jersey server and servlet versions in pom.xml should be the same, right?  Do you have jersey servlet 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the `jersey1` and `jersey2` dependencies here. Remove the following one from your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
  <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
  <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

and add below one

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you need `json` support, then add below one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If possible think to migrate to `jersey2`.